# Angular 6 Getting Loading image error. Getting a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: html, angular, iis

I have an angular project and the home page is mostly HTML. When I type "npm start", all the images successfully loads. When I typed the "npg build --base-href "/MyProject/" --prod, the home page is blank when I create its own website with a unique port. When I add website under Default Web Site, the home page loads but I see the error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

for each image it is trying to load

In the HTML code, it have the following

```
<div> <div><p> <img alt="" src="/assets/img/image123.png" /></a></p></div> </div>
```

I tried added the tilda like `<img alt="" src="~/assets/img/image123.png" />` but it still does not work.

Finally, I loaded again with Chrome and hit F12. I clicked on the 404 error and see the list of images associated with the home page. On an image that has problems loading, I see the page as

http://localhost/assets/img/image123.png

The page is incorrect and will not find the image .

I figure if I can get the images to load under Default WebSite, then it will also load in its own website and portnumber. I am hoping the image location issue fix will fix the loading in IIS.

I also copied/pasted the image file to the root folder where it is located in wwwroot/MyProject/image123.png. That actually loads the file when I changed the following

```
<div> <div><p> <img alt="" src="image123.png" /></a></p></div> </div>
```

However, when I moved the image file to wwwroot/MyProject/assets/image123.png with the following

```
<div> <div><p> <img alt="" src="/assets/img/image123.png" /></a></p></div> </div>
```

it does not load the image. I tried change to the following

```
<img alt="" src="~/assets/img/image123.png" />

<img alt="" src="~assets/img/image123.png" />
```

It does  not load the image file. I am not sure why it can't load the image file when it is located inside the subfolders.

I also tried right click and give everyone full control on the assets folder. I am stumped on this one. It loads in the MyProject folder but not when I move the image file in the subfolders where img folder is located.

Thanks

Comment: try relative path `./assets/img/image123.png` or `assets/img/image123.png`

Comment: nope. that does not work either. I hit F12 and tried http://localhost:80/MyProject/assets/img/image123.png. That does not work. However, with CLI on port 4200, http://localhost:4200/MyProject/assets/img/image123.png, this work. Something about IIS that I don't understand.

Comment: This is a .Net config issue now. Are assets into `wwwroot/MyProject/assets` ?

Comment: Yes. The full folder path to all the image files is wwwroot/MyProject/assets/img. I am using my local IIS to get the angular home page. I am stumped.

Comment: Do you use it because you will deploy it on a IIS or only because you don't want to install an Apache ? If it's the second one, a really easy static server to use is nodeJs http-server. After install it in global `npm install -g http-server` you only need to go to good folder with your terminal and execute `http-server`

Comment: I am using my local IIS to test the page.  If it works on my local IIS, I will be deploying to a real dev IIS. We can't use Apache. IIS only

Comment: I am wondering if its an IIS setting. I read some of the forum authentication IIS setting but they did work for me yet. I gave full control to every user listed when I clicked on Edit Permission on the assets and img folder. still no luck

Comment: You will probably need to package it in .Net (Core) app like explain there : https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa

Comment: Thanks. I read  medium.com steps and in the angular-cli.json, if I specify the image files in the assets section, it will copy the image files to the src folder to serve the static files from. I thought I can specify the img subfolder to load the image files. I am stumped as to why the image files can't be loaded from inside the assets folder.

Comment: My current idea is that your IIS config only allow static serve of one level of folder and not a deep serve

Comment: Your image must be in - localhost/MyProject/assets/img/image123.png

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative path `<div> <div><p> <img alt="" src="./assets/img/image123.png" /></a></p></div> </div>`

As the 'assets' folder is under 'src' and outside of the 'app' folder so you must use relative path (./) which means you will return by one folder

Comment: Yes. I also tried the '/' too and it does not load the image. <img alt="" src/assets/img/image123.png"/>. Still getting 404 error.

Comment: What is the exact URL you are typing in your browser ?

Comment: For my test, I clicked on Browse *.80 (http) and it brings up the homepage. localhost/MyProject/home

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gilsdav and shili for your help. I added ./assets/img/image123.png. I also cleared the browser cache. Gave full control permission to all users for assets and img folders. I got the alias under Default Web Site working but not the independent website with its own port number. It has its own 404 error for styles, main, etc...

In the project angular-cli.json, I added all the images files under "assets" section.

Hope this helps others.